# Ajax - в php файл обработчик приходит не тот текст, который отправляется файлом ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

Есть форма с дропдауном

```
 <form action="" method="post" class="print-month">
        <label for="months-print">Месяц: <select name="month" id="months-print">
                <option value="january">Январь</option>
                <option value="february">Февраль</option>
                <option value="march">Март</option>
                <option value="april">Апрель</option>
                <option value="may">Май</option>
                <option value="june">Июнь</option>
                <option value="july">Июль</option>
                <option value="august">Август</option>
                <option value="september">Сентябрь</option>
                <option value="october">Октябрь</option>
                <option value="november">Ноябрь</option>
                <option value="december">Декабрь</option>
            </select></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Скачать отчет">
    </form>
```

Она обрабаывается следующей функцией ajax

```
    $('.print-month').submit((e) => {
    // e.preventDefault(e);
    let month = $("#months-print :selected").text();
    console.log(month);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/application/core/report_generating.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: month,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'text',
        encode: true,
        success: (data)=>{console.log(data)}
    })
        .done(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
});
```

При отправке проверяю отправленные данные в консоли, получаю "Январь" (либо любой другой выбраный вариант и его текст между тегами option. А вот в файл php, который указан в ajax приходит текст с аттрибуту value тега option, либо оно его просто транслитит как-то. В переменную $month приходит january (к примеру). В чем может быть проблема?
Файл php:

```
    <?php
   if ($_POST['month']) {
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $templateProcessor = new PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Template.docx');


    $templateProcessor->setValue('first', $month);
    $templateProcessor->saveAs('Ouu Shit.docx');
}
```

Comment: обзовите переменную let month по другому
или в select пропишите что то другое

Comment: если меняю переменную на getMonth, допустим, в файле php нужно менять в проверку на $_POST['getMonth'], или оставлять также? Потому что, если меняю, то ничего вообще не происходит. Если оставляю прежним, то всё так же приходит january

Comment: в файл php приходит пост запрос именно с именем select. То есть, если я меняю на name='months', то приходит пост запрос $_POST['months']. Как передать туда именно значени выбранного элемента, которые отправляются в ajax. Есть идеи?

Comment: Судя по всему у вас аякс вообще не отрабатывает. Происходит просто отправка формы.
Раскомментируйте
        // e.preventDefault(e);

Comment: если раскоментить e.preventDefault(e), то в консоль выводится объект с свойством month: "Январь"/ Это если я из let month сделаю объект.

Answer (score 3):

```
e.preventDefault(); // !!!
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: { month: month },
```

---

> ничего не поменялось. В файл php приходит january.

Вы наблюдаете на сервере данные, которые приходят туда в результате стандартного сабмита формы. То есть обработчик `submit` с `e.preventDefault();` не срабатывает.

Варианты -

- в страницу не загружена библиотека jQuery,
- обработчик назначается до того, как в странице появляется элемент `'.print-month'`.

Comment: ничего не поменялось. В файл php приходит january.